# multiple citation problems

Tags: biblatex

I want the citations to be in a specific format. For example, I want to show all the numbers instead of the hyphenated range when consecutive citations.

[image]

Should be like this:

[image]

Moreover, when two/non-consecutive citations I am getting them in separate brackets like:

[image]

But I want them in a single bracket like this:

[image]

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for hyperlinks, citations
\hypersetup{
    citecolor=green,
    colorlinks=True,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
    pdftitle={Thesis_organized},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to manage images
\graphicspath{{./Images/}} % folder where the images or figures are
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % make Figure 1 bold
\usepackage{wrapfig} % for wrapping a figure with words
\usepackage{enumerate}  
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for micro meter
\usepackage{amsmath} % for math fraction symbol
\usepackage{relsize} % for large summation
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek} % greek letters within text
\usepackage{bm} % bold math symbols
\usepackage{verbatim} % for commenting
\usepackage{lipsum} % for MWE
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{dirtytalk} % for quotes
% +---------------------------+
% |  for white space removal  |
% +---------------------------+
\usepackage{paracol}
\globalcounter*
\newsavebox{\tempboxa}
\newsavebox{\tempboxb}
\newsavebox{\textbox}
\newcommand{\splitpar}[2][\textwidth]{% #1 = width of column (optional), #2 = rest of paragraph after split
  \unskip\strut{\parfillskip=0pt\parskip=0pt\par}%
  \global\setbox\textbox=\vbox{\hsize=#1\relax\noindent\strut #2\strut}}
\newcommand{\continuepar}{\unvbox\textbox}
```

The `references.bib` is as:

```
@article{jacksteele,
  title={The role of magnetic resonance imaging in the management of acute spinal cord injury},
  author={jacksteele and Marcoux, Judith and Radha, Bonnie and Clyde, Juliet and Romeo, Benoit},
  journal={Journal of neutritions},
  volume={28},
  number={8},
  pages={1401--1411},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Albert Einstein, Inc. 140 Huguenot Street, 3rd Floor New Rochelle, NY 10801 USA}
} %1

@article{caprcorn,
  title={Molecular ab c d efgh ij k},
  author={Capricorn, Lmk, hjshf ooiwoeri},
  journal={Analytical Physics},
  volume={69},
  number={23},
  pages={4751--4760},
  year={1979},
  publisher={ACS Publications}
}

@article{quarts20183d,
  title={3D MALDI mass spectrometry imaging reveals specific localization of long-chain acylcarnitines within a 10-day time window of spinal cord injury},
  author={Quartz, Jusal and Hauberg-Lotto, XYZ },
  journal={Scientific reports},
  volume={8},
  number={1},
  pages={1--11},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

Also, I am using subsections as chapters in a `main.tex` file.

```
\begin{document}
\vspace{2.0cm}
\begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textbf{\\[60pt]This is just an MWE}\\[60pt]}
    
    \normalsize{Ashoke Kumar\\[60pt]
    % %\vfill
    % % Author addresses
    % \begin{document}
    Ph.D. Thesis Proposal\\
    % % E-mail address for correspondence
    ashoke.kumar@demo.edu\\[60pt]
    
    Department of Biomedical Engineering\\
    Demo University\\[60pt]
    % \centering
    Committee:
    \\
    % 

\end{center}

\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
    \hypersetup{linkcolor = black} % to make \refs black and keep lists blue
\newpage

\section{Specific Aims}
\input{Sections/01_Specific_Aims}

\section{Background}
\input{Sections/02_Background}

\section{Significance}
\input{Sections/03_Significance}

\section{Specific Aim 1}
\input{Sections/04_SpecificAim1}

\section{Specific Aim 2}
\input{Sections/05_SpecificAim2}

\section{Specific Aim 3}
\input{Sections/06_SpecificAim3}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\printbibliography
%\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %abbrv %apalike %ieeetr
%\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Some of the suggestions here and elsewhere didn't work.

Comment: The code shown in the question is sending mixed messages: In the preamble we have `\usepackage[style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex}` and its `\addbibresource` commands, but in the document body `biblatex`'s `\printbibliography` command is commented out, instead we find the BibTeX-based `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`, which will error if `biblatex` is loaded. Can you please clarify which system (`biblatex` or classical BibTeX with `\bibliographystyle`) you use? Ideally you would share a small compilable example document and not big chunks of code referring to files we don't have.

Comment: I commented out the BibTeX lines... just tried to work with combinations which didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `style=ieee,` you are loading `biblatex-ieee`'s IEEE style, whose feature it is to place all citation numbers in separate pairs of brackets. If you don't like that, you can try to mix `bibstyle=ieee,` with a standard numeric citation style `citestyle=numeric,`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=ieee, citestyle=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, 2, 3, 4]]

If you don't actually need IEEE style, you might as well go the full mile and just say `style=numeric,` without any involvement of `biblatex-ieee`.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric, sorting=none]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem [1, 2, 3, 4]]